# Using Linux to load JNI library?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, loader

I need to embed java native library(.so) in standalone binary.
Since I don't have android machine, I'll run it on my **Linux desktop**.
*(Library is x86 version so architecture isn't issue)*

So I'm thinking about create **loader** to run it...

**Question:**

1. Can I use **C** loader program that `dlopen` the target library?
   with calling `JNI_Onload`(entry point) inside my loader, would library runs well?
2. Or is there any smarter way to *embed* JNI library?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `dlopen` is literally how the JVM loads a library itself. That is the easy bit.

The problems start after that, however:

1. The library might use the `RegisterNatives` approach of mapping Java `native` methods to function pointers.
2. `JNI_OnLoad` expects to receive a `JNIEnv*` (basically a big table of function pointers) that manipulate a JVM. If you are not using a pre-provided JNI interface (of a JVM on your platform), expect to reimplement a good chunk of it.
3. The library might have dependencies on Java code. You will have to fake that functionality in your JNI boilerplate or, again, run a JVM with those classes loaded.

And of course there is the **legal aspect** of taking basically someone else's code, repackaging it, and running it in an unexpected fashion.